# No module named 'ptvsd.repl' in Python remote debug

Tags: python, remote-debugging

I have followed [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-cross-platform-remote) to install ptvsd 3.2.0, and put below code in the very beginning of target code.

```
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach('my_secret')
```

If run this code, I got error:

```
File "~/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ptvsd/__init__.py", line 87, in enable_attach
    return _attach_server().enable_attach(secret, address, certfile, keyfile, redirect_output)
File "~/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ptvsd/__init__.py", line 31, in _attach_server
    import ptvsd.attach_server
File "~/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ptvsd/attach_server.py", line 40, in <module>
    import ptvsd.debugger as vspd
File "~/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ptvsd/debugger.py", line 49, in <module>
    import ptvsd.repl as _vspr
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ptvsd.repl'

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today. I've checked the [last version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ptvsd/3.2.0) and was released yesterday. I've decided to roll back to version 3.1.0, and that is working fine for me.

I've reported the problem to the [gitter room](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/PTVS). I'll update this answer as soon as I get more information.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I would like to use it in lastest Visual Studio Code (win10 x64) for remote debugging in Python. I have tried all versions of ptvsd. All of them are not work. The IDE always complain debugger crash. On the remote side, I can see connection established.

Answer (score 0):

The `ptvsd` module is not using semantic versioning, which means you cannot safely update it whenever you like. The plan is to switch to semantic versioning when it is fully decoupled from Visual Studio.

`ptvsd==3.2.0` was released at the same time that Visual Studio 2017 Update 15.3 because they have dependencies on each other. If you also update Visual Studio then you should update to `ptvsd==3.2.0`. Otherwise, stay with an older version.

Currently Visual Studio Code requires `ptvsd<3`. It has not been updated for recent changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed it globally by specifying certain python because my default python is 3.9 but for azure-functions I needed it installed in 3.8

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -m pip install ptvsd`

Of course you must replace my python version with yours

But [***ptvsd***](https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd) IS DEPRECATED and replaced with [***debugpy***](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy)